# Can Grails / GORM filter association results w/o N+1 queries?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, has-many

I've got a legacy schema where there are effective dated records in the child end of a hasMany association.  In this case I want the end dated records excluded from the results on the parent objects and am trying to avoid an N+1 query solution.

I'm able to filter them like this and generate an appropriate looking query:

```
def companyStaffList = CompanyStaff.findAll ( [ max: params.max, sort: params.sort, order: params.order ] ) {
      companyID == params.id && 
      compRecords { effectiveDate < new Date() && endDate > new Date() }
}
```

The generated query has the join and the filter:

```
        select [ ...the base fields + the associated fields... ] from company_staff 
    this_ inner join person_compensation comprecord1_ on 
    this_.personID=comprecord1_.personID where 
(this_.companyID=? and ((comprecord1_.effectiveDate<? and comprecord1_.endDate>?))) 
    order by this_.lName asc limit ?
```

Unfortunately, once I start accessing the associated fields, I see a second query that doesn't propagate the filtering criteria:

```
select [ the associated fields ] from person_compensation 
comprecord0_ where comprecord0_.personID=?
```

Please advise if there's a principled way to do this or if I'm just asking too much.

Answer (score 1):

You're accessing child collection `compRecords`, correct?

Then the first query fetched only those `CompRecord`s that fit the search criteria.

Imagine `CompanyStaff staffA` that has one `CompRecord` that fits the search and one that doesn't. That data is not suitable to completely fill in `CompanyStaff.compRecords`. Then you start accessing `staffA.compRecords` collection, any you will need to also enumerate those `CompRecord`s that didn't fit the query.

To avoid N+1 reads, I'd query child `CompRecord`. But then you won't be able to paginate `CompanyStaff`s, but only `CompRecord`s:

```
CompRecords.findAll ([max: params.max, sort: params.sort, order: params.order]) {
  effectiveDate < new Date() && endDate > new Date() &&
  staff {
    companyID == params.id
  }
}
```

If it's OK to fetch only a single `CompRecord` for a `CompanyStaff`, you can use HQL to fetch an untyped collection containing both `CompanyStaff` and `CompRecord` fields.

Comment: Thanks for the response--great idea.  Unfortunately, the lack of pagination on the CompanyStaff likely makes this impractical for my use.  Also, I couldn't get sort to work using 'staff.lastName' in this style query.  I had to translate it to a criteria query to get ordering on the parent association.

Comment: You still can use HQL and get an untyped result set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use eager fetching to avoid N+1. Look at [GORM](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html) documentation where talks about "Querying with Eager Fetching"